# Variable does not change with each loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel VBA so I apologize for the very elementary level of coding. Basically I have a table that has headers like Age and Name.

I am trying to write a code to find all the headers with "Age" and copy the values into another cell, compiling all the ages under a separate table essentially.

[Screenshot of my working sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI96f.png)

I have included a `searchAge` variable that is `""Age " & i"`, with`i`increasing after every loop. This is then put into a Find function under findAge. The problem I am facing is that the cell that `findAge` is finding for is always "Age 1" and does not update to "Age 2" when `i` is increasing.

```
    Dim rngSearch As Range
    Dim rngLast As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim firstCellAddress As String
    Dim findAge As Range
    Dim searchAge As String
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1

    'set the search range
    Set rngSearch = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:R100")

    'specify last cell in the range
    Set rngLast = rngSearch.Cells(rngSearch.Cells.Count)

    searchAge = "Age " & i
    Set findAge = rngSearch.Find(What:=searchAge, MatchByte:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:="Age", After:=rngLast, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        firstCellAddress = rngFound.Address
        Do
            Set rngFound = rngSearch.FindNext(rngFound)
            MsgBox (rngFound.Offset(1, 0).Value & findAge.Value & i)
            findAge.Offset(1, 0) = rngFound.Offset(1, 0).Value
            i = i + 1
        Loop Until rngFound.Address = firstCellAddress
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your condition means you will only ever had 1 `i`... `firstCellAddress = rngFound.Address` and your condition is `Loop Until rngFound.Address = firstCellAddress`.

```
If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
    firstCellAddress = rngFound.Address '<--- THIS ##########
    Do
        Set rngFound = rngSearch.FindNext(rngFound)
        MsgBox (rngFound.Offset(1, 0).Value & findAge.Value & i)
        findAge.Offset(1, 0) = rngFound.Offset(1, 0).Value
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until rngFound.Address = firstCellAddress '<--- THIS ###########
End If
```

You *should* only be seeing 1 messagebox when this runs.

---

I believe you want this *INSIDE* of your loop, so the `i` iterates for `searchAge.`..

```
searchAge = "Age " & i
Set findAge = rngSearch.Find(What:=searchAge, MatchByte:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Someone formatted/indented your code in the post, which I believe is inherently your issue.  You would have seen what was inside of your loop had you indented appropriately (loop starts with `Do` and end with `Loop`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Cyril. If you indent your code correctly you will see the issues. Try This Instead:

```
Sub dothisagain()

    Dim rngSearch As Range
    Dim rngLast As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim firstCellAddress As String
    Dim findAge As Range
    Dim searchAge As String
    Dim i As Integer

    'set the search range
    Set rngSearch = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:R100")

    'specify last cell in the range
    Set rngLast = rngSearch.Cells(rngSearch.Cells.Count)


    Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:="Age", After:=rngLast, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            firstCellAddress = rngFound.Address
            i = 1
            searchAge = "Age " & i
            Set findAge = rngSearch.Find(What:=searchAge, MatchByte:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(rngFound)
            MsgBox (rngFound.Offset(1, 0).Value & findAge.Value & i)
            findAge.Offset(1, 0) = rngFound.Offset(1, 0).Value
            i = i + 1
            Do
                firstCellAddress = rngFound.Address
                Set rngFound = rngSearch.FindNext(rngFound)
                searchAge = "Age " & i
                Set findAge = rngSearch.Find(What:=searchAge, MatchByte:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                findAge.Offset(1, 0) = rngFound.Offset(1, 0).Value
                i = i + 1
            Loop Until rngFound.Address <> firstCellAddress
        End If

End Sub
```